# Use factory and builder pattern to create some class the best way approach

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, hook

I have the factory class and use builder to create the class for factory class method. In the below example, I replace custom builder to StringBuilder to simplified example.

Before create builder to class there are some behavior is same. I don't want to write duplicate code so I create base factory class to encapsulate method and derivative method or delegate to builder.
So child class can override method to hook builder and operate builder.

Full Code.

```
public abstract class FactoryBase
{
    protected delegate void HookSomeStringHandler(StringBuilder builder);

    protected HookSomeStringHandler OnHookSomeStringHandler;

    /// <summary>
    /// You can override <see cref="InnerHookSomeString"/> to hook builder.
    /// </summary>
    public string GetSomeStringA()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(GetType().Name); // need all child class name              
        InnerHookSomeString(sb);   // hook StringBuilder to append some string
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Child class can override this to hook StringBuilder <see cref="GetSomeStringA"/>
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void InnerHookSomeString(StringBuilder builder)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// You can override method to hook stringBuilder or using delegate action to hook stringBuilder. 
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string GetSomeStringB(Action<StringBuilder> outerHook)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(GetType().Name);  // need all child class name              
        outerHook?.Invoke(sb);      // hook StringBuilder to append some string
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use register delegate to hook stringBuilder. <see cref="OnHookSomeStringHandler"/>
    /// </summary>
    public string GetSomeStringC()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(GetType().Name);                // need all child class name              
        OnHookSomeStringHandler?.Invoke(sb);      // hook StringBuilder to append some string
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class ChildA : FactoryBase
{
    public ChildA()
    {
        OnHookSomeStringHandler += (sb) =>
        {
            // TODO do something by GetSomeStringC
        };
    }

    protected override void InnerHookSomeString(StringBuilder builder)
    {
        // TODO do something by GetSomeStringA
    }

    public override string GetSomeStringB(Action<StringBuilder> outerHook)
    {
        return base.GetSomeStringB((sb) =>
        {
            // TODO do something by GetSomeStringB
        });
    }
}
```

*Note: The Builder in `GetSomeString` does not need to add a string or doing something every time so I don't use the abstract method to enforce child class that must be to override.*

I have three ideal to this situation.

1. `GetSomeStringA` use `InnerHookSomeString` to hook `StringBuilder` and child class can operate builder but this way of writing maybe user don't know this approach so need to use tag `<see cref>`.
2. `GetSomeStringB` use override to hook `StringBuilder` and can hook builder in the outer but this way of writing looks ugly.
3. `GetSomeStringC` similar to `GetSomeStringA`, it is done by registering a delegate and need to use tag too to prompt user.

Which one of the above three methods is better to maintain or readable? 
Does anyone have a better idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your intend. Generally all three solutions are bad design.
Also given you provided context, it appears that the term or name *Factory* does not fit. I don't see any instance being created. I just see some string assembly. This class should be named `SomeStringCreator`. Naming a class *...Factory* implies that the type is an implementation of the Factory pattern, like naming a class *...Builder*  would imply that the class implements the Builder pattern.

For a better understanding let's assume we want to implement a `Logger` class. This logger has a public `Log(string message)` method. Internally the `Logger` is able to route the output to a specific data sink e.g. file or database. The client of the `Logger` is a normal developer that wants to log a message. But developers/inheritors are allowed to extend or modify the behavior of the `Logger` e.g. change the data sink.

---

If your intend is to have an *abstract* base class that provides/encapsulates some common behavior, then **2)** and **3)** don't work (well).

`abstract` class means the class will not provide ready-to use behavior. The missing logic is required to be implemented by the inheritor, although some basic logic is already provided via `private`, `protected` or `virtual` members.
If the class is ready-to-use, then it wouldn't be declared `abstract` and would only provide `virtual` members where extensibility is wanted.

**2)**
This solution exposes the extensible behavior via a parameter of a public method, making the behavior public:

```
// Forces the caller to mix high-level and low-level details in a high-level context
public void Log(string message, Action<string> persistMessage)
{
  var formattedMessage = AddHeaderToMessage(message);
  persistMessage.Invoke(formattedMessage);
}
```

This example forces the caller of your API to care about the internals (low-level) i.e the logic used to achieve the class' goal, which is to log a message (high-level). This is not what a base class is for (delegate internals to the public API) or generally how a clean class API should be designed.

Internals (the logic how the class accomplishes its goal) must be hidden (`private` or `protected`). That's encapsulation.
The logic (low-level details) of a class should not be injected as method parameter, when the method is intended to operate in a high-level context. In our example the client only wants to log a message and not implement or provide an implementation of the persistence logic. He doesn't want to mix logging (high-level) and logger implementation (low-level).

**3)**
Is not very convenient. Note that generally a base class should always provide a useful default logic to achieve satisfy its purpose. This means the delegate must be initialized at least. What makes the delegate a bad choice is that it is not the expected way when providing extensibility. The developer is always looking for virtual methods to override. Delegates are good to allow the caller/client to define callbacks.

**1)**
In the context of a class that is intended to be extended by an inheritor the solution **1)** is the right way. But your current implementation is error prone.
Note that generally a base class should always provide a useful default logic to achieve satisfy its purpose (otherwise use an interface). An `abstract` base class should declare all the required members to accomplish the goal also `abstract` in order to force the inheritor to provide an implementation or provide a `virtual` default implementation:

```
// WRONG
public void Log(string message)
{
  var formattedMessage = AddHeaderToMessage(message);

  // Will fail silently, if the inheritor forgets to override this member
  PersistMessage(formattedMessage);
}

protected virtual void PersistMessage(string message)
{      
}
```

Either provide a default implementation:

```
// Right
public void Log(string message)
{
  var formattedMessage = AddHeaderToMessage(message);

  // Can't fail, because the base class provides a default implementation
  PersistMessage(formattedMessage);
}

protected virtual void PersistMessage(string message)
{      
  // Default implementation
  SaveToFile(message);
}
```

Or make the member `abstract`:

```
// Right
public void Log(string message)
{
  var formattedMessage = AddHeaderToMessage(message);

  // Can't fail, because the inheritor is forced by the compiler to override this member
  PersistMessage(formattedMessage);
}

protected abstract void PersistMessage(string message);
```

Or let the unimplemented member throw an exception.
Use this solution only when the two previous solutions won't work, so generally don't use this. The point is that exception are only thrown at run-time while a missing override of an `abstract` class is generating compile-time errors:

```
// Right
public void Log(string message)
{
  var formattedMessage = AddHeaderToMessage(message);

  // Forced to fail at run-time, because the default implementation 
  // will throw a NotImplementedException (non-silent fail)
  PersistMessage(formattedMessage);
}

protected virtual void PersistMessage(string message)
{      
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

---

If you want to make the class extensible for the client, when interacting with the API, then of course **2)** is the solution to go with.
For example if you want the client to be able to modify the formatting of the logged message e.g. which headers or tags to use or their order of appearance, then you would allow the method to accept the related logic or configuration as a parameter. This parameter could be a delegate, configuration object or a format string which uses placeholders like `"<timestamp><callerContext><errorLevel> - <message>"`:

```
public void Log(string message, string formatPattern)
{
  var formattedMessage = AddHeaderToMessage(message, formatPattern);
  PersistMessage(formattedMessage);
}

protected virtual void PersistMessage(string formattedMessage)
{      
  SaveToFile(message);
}
```

To keep the API clean, consider to expose public properties and/or a constructor overload to configure the instance with a e.g., delegate or configuration object/parameter:

```
// Constructor
public Logger(string formatPattern)
{
  _formatPattern = formatPattern;
}

public void Log(string message)
{
  var formattedMessage = AddHeaderToMessage(message, _formatPattern);
  PersistMessage(formattedMessage);
}

protected virtual void PersistMessage(string formattedMessage)
{      
  SaveToFile(message);
}
```

Note that both solutions operate on the same level of details: all parameters relate to the log message and not to internal implementation details like *how* the message is actually persisted. In this context the reasonable level of details regarding the logging itself, would be a configuration parameter to control which data sink to use e.g. email or database.

Comment: Nice answer but I'm sorry maybe my example is misunderstanding. Actually I use builder Pattern create some class but in this example I replace custom builder to StringBuilder to simplified example..

Comment: This doesn't really matter. If you would've passed a `StringReader` to the methods instead, the result is still the same: use the modified first version of your examples. See my answer on how to modify it. Your problem was somewhat confusing so I chose a general scenario like a logger. It seems it was too abstract to move away from your scenario. Do you have issues to transfer my answer to your example using a `StringBuilder` as the parameter instead a log message? The point is not the parameter type, but the way you design the class that is intended to be extended using inheritance.

Comment: Finally I use the default implementation. 
I move the same behavior `sb.Append(GetType().Name)` into `InnerHookSomeString` method to be default implementation.
In my case, an abstract method is not suitable because my child class maybe don't need to override InnerHookSomeString method.
Thanks for your explanations in details.